# How to find depth of <div> tag in html using python?

Tags: python, html, regex

How should I go about finding the depth of this block -

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, it should be 3.
Any clue/code will help.

Comment: [Parsing HTML using regex? You must be superhuman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4099593)

Comment: Yes, parsing it using regex.

Comment: did you forget to include the first < of the divs, or are they not there?

Comment: StackOverflow was giving some error.... it is what you think.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do this. I would [not recommend](http://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t%20use%20regex%20to%20parse%20html) using a regex to parse XML though.

One way is to use the [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser) that comes standard with Python:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.depth = 1

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print 'Encountered %s at depth %d.' % (tag, self.depth)
        self.depth += 1

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.depth -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = '''
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    '''

    MyHTMLParser().feed(html)
```

Running this script produces:

```
Encountered div at depth 1.
Encountered div at depth 2.
Encountered div at depth 3.
```

Comment: I suggest changing the link to *google.com* instead of *google.be*

Comment: Thank You Rodin! That's helps.